# Deepboost prediction of type = "prob" using caret package is not working

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret

I was trying to fit `deepboost` model using `caret` package. I have downloaded the data from [this link](https://www.kaggle.com/multi8ball/prostate-cancer)

```
library(caret)

prc <- read.csv("Prostate_Cancer.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

prc <- na.omit(prc[-1])  #removes the first variable(id) from the data set.

normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))) }

prc_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(prc[2:9], normalize))
summary(prc_n)

df <- cbind(prc_n,diagnosis_result= prc$diagnosis_result)
head(df,2)

# create a list of 70% of the rows in the original dataset we can use for training
set.seed(123)
training <- sample(nrow(df), 0.7 * nrow(df))

dataTrain <- df[training,]
dataTest <- df[-training,]

trainControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5,
                             savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=T)
#Deepboost
set.seed(7)
fit.dpb <- train(diagnosis_result~., data=dataTrain, method="deepboost", 
                             trControl=trainControl)
fit.dpb

dpb_cal_prob <- predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTrain, type = "prob")
dpb_val_prob <- predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTest, type = "prob")

dpb_cal <- predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTrain)
dpb_val <- predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTest)

#variable importance of variables
varImp(fit.dpb,scale=T)
plot(varImp(fit.dpb,scale=T))
```

Both `varImp` and `predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTrain, type = "prob")` is not working. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: normalizing data should be applied within resampling/only on train data. This way you are preventing data leakage. The call `predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTrain)` works? What does it output? Are you sure `"deepboost"` has a `varImp` method?

Comment: `predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTrain)` works but `predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTrain, type = "prob") is not working.

Comment: In terms of B and M. I am not sure whether deepboost have varImp or not. In `caret` source code `prob = NULL` is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source code for deepboost](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/deepboost.R), the model can not predict probabilities and it does not have a varimp method. See differences in model list elements compared with [glmnet source code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/glmnet.R) for instance which can do these things.

EDIT: To make the deepboost model predict probabilities you need to modify the source code:

create a:

```
deepboost_prob <- list(label = "DeepBoost",
                       library = "deepboost",....
```

where you will copy the whole source code: https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/deepboost.R

Add a prob slot:

```
deepboost_prob$prob <- function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
  if(!is.data.frame(newdata)) 
    newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  probs <- deepboost:::predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "response")
  probs <- as.data.frame(probs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(probs) <- modelFit@classes
  probs
}
```

check if it works:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
data(Sonar)

trainControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                             number = 5,
                             savePredictions = TRUE,
                             classProbs = TRUE)

set.seed(7)
fit.dpb <- train(x = Sonar[1:150,1:60],
                 y = Sonar$Class[1:150],
                 method = deepboost_prob, 
                  trControl = trainControl,
                 tuneLength = 1)
Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
3: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
4: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
5: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
6: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
```

I get warnings with the original deepboost implementation as well

```
predict(fit.dpb, Sonar[200:208,1:60], type = "prob")
          M         R
1 0.3721210 0.6278790
2 0.4087576 0.5912424
3 0.3700643 0.6299357
4 0.3656457 0.6343543
5 0.5232370 0.4767630
6 0.2439648 0.7560352
7 0.3687249 0.6312751
8 0.2679716 0.7320284
9 0.3292782 0.6707218
```

Comment: I do have seen this. Can it be solved, actually that was my question.

Comment: Based on the ref manual: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deepboost/deepboost.pdf, probabilities can be returned. This would require changing the source code. I can do that and update the answer later when I have time. as for VarImp I don't think there is a method for this.

Comment: Do you get warnings: "In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored" when you run deepboost tuning via caret?

Comment: No, I did not receive such warning message.

Comment: D you get warnings with the function I posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211368/discussion-between-bappa-das-and-missuse).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
predict(fit.dpb, newdata = dataTrain, type = "response")
```

Does that not give the probabilities you want?

It appears to for my deepboost models.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, `type = "response"` does not work with `caret::train` function. It works if I train the model using `deepboost` function. If you run the example given above using `caret` package it gives you ```Warning messages:
1: In train.default(x = Sonar[1:150, 1:60], y = Sonar$Class[1:150],  :
  Class probabilities were requested for a model that does not implement them```. The source code for `caret::deepboost` does not have predict probabilities.

Comment: Thank yoy! Perhaps a msg to Max Kuhn the caret creator may be in order.